# How would I check if the pathname is a value like "search" or "settings" in .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.html?id=$1 [L]
```

and all it does it moves the url paramater "id" to my main directory, so essentially [all it does it this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxEri.png)

but with the rewrite rule, [you get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0ygl.png)

In my .htaccess if the pathname is "search" or "settings" for example, I want it to ignore that rule and go straight to search.html or settings.html.

Thanks, Ender

Comment: Well, have you bothered to read the documentation of the tool you use? Because that explains how to do that. Giving easy examples.